# Not able to format namenode in hadoop-2.6.0 multi node installation

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, installation, hadoop-yarn

I am trying to install Hadoop-2.6.0 in ubuntu 14-04 machine. 5 node cluster. But when I format the namenode, it gives me the following error

> No command 'hdfs' found, did you mean:  Command 'hfs' from package
>   'hfsutils-tcltk' (universe)  Command 'hdfls' from package 'hdf4-tools'
>   (universe) hdfs: command not found

And in the .bashrc file, I can't understand what path to give for Hadoop_home/bin, as I don't see any folder "bin" inside Hadoop installation.

Please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these lines in `.bashrc`:

```
export HADOOP_HOME=/path/to/your/hadoop/installation
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
```

As for,

> I don't see any folder "bin" inside Hadoop installation

Check whether you have binary distribution or source. Download `hadoop-2.6.0.tar.gz` from [Hadoop Distributions](https://www.apache.org/dist/hadoop/core/hadoop-2.6.0/), in case you have source distribution.

Comment: yeah... The tar I downloaded didn't have the bin directory. Downloaded again, and now I can see the bin folder. Thanks for your quick reply.